# AspectJ constructor force factory pattern

Tags: java, aspectj, factory-pattern

I want to change the object return from call to a constuctor

**FROM**

```
public class A  {

   public A(){
   }

   public String sayHello() {
    return "hello";
   }

   public String foo() {
      return "foo";
   }

}
```

**TO**

```
public class AWrapped extends A {

     private A wrapped;

     public AWrapped() {
       super();
     }


     public AWrapped(A pWrapped) {
        wrapped=pWrapped;
     }

     public String foo() {
       return wrapped.foo();
     }

     public String sayHello {
        return "gday mate";
     }

}
```

What i want to do is to change the object that is returned from a call

```
A a = new A();
a.sayHello() returns "gday mate"
```

a is an instaceof AWrapped

I understand that this would usually be done with a factory pattern but I dont have access to the code of A or the code that makes new A's.  And there are 1000s of places that A can be created.

It seems that Aspectj might do the trick, but i dont know much about it, If AspectJ would do the trick how to I get around the infinite wrapping i need to know that its being consturcted from within and aspect so it doesnt wrapp it again.

Thanks for the help
Jon

Comment: If you create a `new A()` later, it will still say "hello". Guess, the first line of your last example should read `A a = new AWrapped()`

Comment: Thanks Marko that makes sense, I still need to solve the problem so im going to try and make a custom classloader and see if i can get around it that way. Thanks again

Comment: @user898333, that seems like the way to go. Please, once you have solved your problem post the outline of it here as the answer to your question.

Comment: You can also repackage the old code and a new "emulation" layer with the having the same signatures. See http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/ for automated repackaging

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik that's not true. AspectJ can change the return value of a constructor call (or rather replace the constructor call with something else), see Fred's answer

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you right you could do the following:

I've created three packages:

[image: package structure]

- aspectj for the aspect and AWrapped.java
- unknown for A.java (could also be Bytecode but then you have to use [Load Time Weaving](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw.html))
- main to test `A a = new A();`

MyAspect to return the AWrapped object if a `new()` call is made on class A:

```
package aspectj;

import unknown.A;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

    @Pointcut("call(unknown.A.new(..)) && !within(aspectj..*)")
    public static void init(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    }

    @Around("init(pjp)")
    public Object initAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable{
        Object ret = pjp.proceed();
        return new AWrapped((A) ret);
        }

}
```

For testing:

```
package main;

import unknown.A;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.sayHello());
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
gday mate
```