# AspectJ: Can I intercept object creation and replace with anther object?

Tags: aop, aspectj

I have some legacy code which will do:

MyInterface obj = new MyImpl

I'd like to intercept the creation of MyImpl and return another object say MyOtherImpl

Is it doable?

Thanks

Comment: yup. check out `around` advice.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291053/aspectj-constructor-force-factory-pattern

Comment: this example is slightly different: AWrapped extends from A. While in my case MyImpl and MyOtherImpl is independent impl. I got ClassCastException complain that MyOtherImpl cannot be cast to MyImpl :(

Answer (score 0):

As I have explained in [my answer your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25305900/1082681), this does not work with sibling classes, only with subclasses.